# Changing colours at posh-git/powershell prompt

Tags: git, powershell, posh-git

I can not work out how to change the `-b` flag and the quoted string to something more readable.

I have tried changing *git* settings, *posh-git* settings, and *powershell* settings. [This stack answer was my last hope](https://superuser.com/questions/950875/how-to-set-custom-syntax-coloring-for-powershell-5-0) but I couldn't find which [token-flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.language.tokenkind(v=vs.85).aspx) i need to change :(

Can anyone give an example of how I can change all switches/flags and quoted strings to something brighter? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.language.tokenkind%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you referenced:

> **Parameter**
>   A parameter to a command, always begins with a dash ('-'), followed by the parameter name. Tokens with this kind are always instances of ParameterToken.
>   […]
>   **StringExpandable**
>   A double quoted string literal. Tokens with this kind are always instances of StringExpandableToken even if there are no nested tokens to expand.
>   **StringLiteral**
>   A single quoted string literal. Tokens with this kind are always instances of StringLiteralToken.

So this should do what you want:

```bsh
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Parameter -ForegroundColor Gray
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind StringExpandable -ForegroundColor Cyan
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind StringLiteral -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

Comment: Thanks. I had previously tried `Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind StringExpandable -ForegroundColor Cyan` and it failed which made me discount this approach. But your first suggestion worked, which seemed strange. So I tried `Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind String -ForegroundColor Cyan` and that worked for the strings!